# I am trying to install PyQt6 and am getting metadata error

Tags: python, python-3.10, pyqt6

New to Python. Attempting to install PyQt6.  This is my error. Any suggestions?

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

 × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
 │ exit code: 1
 ╰─> [29 lines of output]
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
         hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
     AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
         main()
       File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
         json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
       File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
         whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
       File "C:\Users\AFEANA~1.BRC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t089xght\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
         project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
       File "C:\Users\AFEANA~1.BRC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t089xght\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
         project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
       File "C:\Users\AFEANA~1.BRC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t089xght\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
         self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
       File "project.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
         super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
       File "C:\Users\AFEANA~1.BRC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t089xght\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
         super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
       File "C:\Users\AFEANA~1.BRC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t089xght\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
         self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
       File "C:\Users\AFEANA~1.BRC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t089xght\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
         "specify a working qmake or add it to PATH")
     sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
     [end of output]
```

I had similar issues with my home system and got it figured out. The work system is using PyCharm.  On my home system I needed to go into the PyCharm folder and run in venv. I am unable to do that here at work. So I am giving up and just sticking to PyQt5 here.
Thanks.

Comment: PyQt6 is not yet updated for Python 3.10. You need to install Python 3.9 instead.

Comment: What version did you get it to run on? I just tried with Python 3.9.12 and still the same issue.

Comment: I have it running on Python 3.9.11 but now I realized it was the PyQt6-tools package that I had problems with Python 3.10 with. How are you installing PyQt6? I found your error "specify a working qmake or add it to PATH" at this link: https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-December/043460.html and it talks about either use the Python wheel that comes with Qt bundled or install Qt yourself first.

Comment: pip install PyQt6

Comment: same failure with 3.9.11

Comment: C:\Users\Afeana.BRCMLTD\Downloads>pip install PyQt6-6.2.3-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl
ERROR: PyQt6-6.2.3-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_14_universal2.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Your command line doesn't look like mac os x but you are installing the mac version. What OS are you using?

Comment: you are correct, I am getting frustrated. I had tried the AMD.  OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  C:\Users\Afeana.BRCMLTD\Downloads>pip install PyQt6-6.2.3-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: PyQt6-6.2.3-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

What version of python did you install? Because i had the same problem and for me the update to a recent version of python (3.9 to 3.10) have solved the problem

Comment: I just installed 3.10.4